# How do you use glDrawElements with GL_UNSIGNED_INT for the indices?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, opengl-es, objective-c++

I'm trying to draw 3d objects that have more than 65536 vertices on the iPad, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. My original model that used GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT worked just fine, but now with GL_UNSIGNED_INT, I can't get anything to show up using the glDrawElements command. It's like the renderer is ignoring my glDrawElements line completely. The portion of my rendering loop that I'm referencing is below:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(assemblyObj->vertices[0])*6, &assemblyObj->vertices[0]);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(assemblyObj->vertices[0])*6, &assemblyObj->vertices[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < assemblyObj->numObjects; i++)
{
     glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, assemblyObj->partList[i].faceArray.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &assemblyObj->partList[i].faceArray[0]);
}

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
```

vertices is defined as:

```
vector<float> vertices;
```

and each faceArray is defined as:

```
vector<UInt32> faceArray;
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong that is preventing my geometry from drawing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stock OpenGL ES does not support `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` for indices.

From the [GLES glDrawElements man page](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml):

> GL_INVALID_ENUM is generated if type is not GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE or GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT.

This restriction is relaxed when GL_OES_element_index_uint is supported.

If you don't have support on the target platform, your best bet is to munge your mesh in multiple sub-meshes with `< 64K` indices for each.

As to ipad specifically, as far as I know, [iOS does not support this extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html) (See Supported extensions), but you can verify the extension list on the actual device if you want to make sure.

Comment: Is doing this faster than drawing with glDrawArrays? I can do the same thing I'm doing now with glDrawArrays, but I want to render at as many FPS as possible.

Comment: I figured it out, I just render each object using it's own vertex array and it works just fine. I'm rendering about 125,000 vertices with a total of 90 models and it is usable, renders about 12 frames per second. Now I'm just trying to figure out if there is anything I can do to speed up rendering. Any suggestions?

Comment: This answer is incorrect, `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` is supported for `glDrawElements` if `GL_OES_element_index_uint` is implemented (which it is in iOS, according to <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>).

Comment: @rich.e Thank you! I stumbled across this while searching, and  #include'ing that file fixed my issue for iOS (it was in external code, so using this seems preferable to rewriting the code to work with GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT).

Comment: @rich.e: clarified my answer to include mention of the extension. However, can someone clarify if ios indeed supports the extension? the page I found said it doesn't. Just the fact that a header has the definition is not enough to claim support.

Comment: I can verify that glDrawElements works correctly with unsigned int values in iOS 5.0 on an iPhone 4, I haven't tested anything older.  As for the apple docs, I put more faith in header files, they rarely keep them up to date.

Comment: @rich.e: thanks for checking. As for headers showing extensions, they don't necessarily imply support, just that you can program against the extension _if present_ in GL_EXTENSIONS_STRING. Hence my previous comment. Finally found a page with all the data: http://www.lastrayofhope.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Screen-shot-2011-07-24-at-05.17.56.png Looks like it started to show up in iOS 4.